# Links Not Doing Anything

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, commerce

I'm making a rather simple online store page at http://pyentertainment.com/store.html integrating PayPal for payments, and just when I thought I was done I noticed none of the hyperlinks seem to do anything.  By this I mean when I click them (I'm using Chrome and the same happens on other browsers too), on the status bar where it normally says "loading www.xyz.com" it changes to something for a fraction of a second and then disappears, not loading a new page; it's way too fast for me to catch what it says.
This happens to the links on the nav bar and to the social media links on the right.

Some context: When you click on an item, the page dims and an iframe comes up showcasing said product, with PayPal cart buttons.  View cart/Add to cart open a new tab, but if you close them by clicking "continue shopping" they throw another error which although I'm not too concerned about might be the cause of the problem; I know iframes can be iffy to work with.
I'd appreciate any help.  The links work on the rest of the domain, too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, the issue ended up being that I had the entire body to check for clicks, and if the user clicked outside the item display box while it was on, dim it out, like this:

```
$('body').click(function(event)
{
  if(!$(event.target).is('#productDisplay'))
  {
    $("#darkenBackground").fadeOut();
    $("#productDisplay").attr('src','buy/loading.html');
    return false;
  }
});
```

I got rid of that feature and instead added a little close button to do the same thing.  The links work now! Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading firebug from here:

[Firebug Home Page](http://getfirebug.com/)

And watching what loads while you're loading your page, it will tell you if the resource is actually being located/served when the page is processing.  If it's not, you may want to review how you built your links toe ensure they're properly configured.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Where in Firebug can I see that network activity?

Comment: actually I think I found it; when I click on a link I get 3 requests, 2 of the css files for styling, and 1 for the "loading" page that the iframe loads by default on load, but absolutely nothing from where I actually want to go.

Answer (score 0):

i cant give a full answer but it looks like its your dimmer specificly the part that detects the body click. try putting it into an if statement to check that the functon has been called before running the body click function

EDIT

something like

```
if(product displayed) {
look for click event on body
}
```

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean.  To see if the dimming function has been called? And how would I force the click to act upon the body rather than the iframe?